# SSL website append https in child URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, ssl, cdn

All,

I am working on website, which developed by PHP. It was secured by SSL.

I need to pass a URL from a function, which delivers the content. this URL will be passed like below

Webhost: 'example.com';

Now this CDN url is prefix with https://asdf.com in console..
But It needs to be like http://asdf.com.

I know that, we can add  http before the url, to access http websites from secured sites. But the above syntax should not contain www or http ot https..

But the syntax wont allow to prefix http in front of the url.

Looking for kind help from friends..

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: what about create to constant _CDN1_WEBHOST_ = 'https' & _CDN2_WEBHOST_ = 'http'

Answer (score 0):

What about use constants?

```
<?php
   $CDN_WEBHOST == true ? define("HTTP_VAR", "https://") : define("HTTP_VAR", "http://");
   echo HTTP_VAR . example.com;
?>
```

Comment: Hi RePRO, Thanks for your time in this. I tried this way but still the console response says this URL as https://-http://xxx.com.

Comment: My function is----                                                                     function load() {
  webHost = 'asdf.com';                                                                                    }  ---- It should not modified anything append with it, coz this is the syntax for using this function vriable.... Any thing needs to change in SSL configuration?

Comment: Can anyone help me in this? please.